# How to prove invariance implies quadrature about Haar measure?

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure

I'm reading [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.08010), which contains a lemma named as 'Invariance Implies Quadrature'. The lemma is stated as follows.

> **Lemma** Let $f$ be a function from $O(d)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and let $H$ be a finite subgroup of $O(d)$. If $$\mathbb{E}_{P\in H}f(P)=\mathbb{E}_{P\in H}f(PQ_0)$$ for all $Q_0\in O(d)$, then $$\mathbb{E}_{P\in H}f(P)=\mathbb{E}_{Q\in O(d)}f(Q)$$
>   where $Q$ is chosen according to Haar measure and $P$ is uniform on $H$.
>
> *proof.* $$\mathbb{E}_{Q\in O(d)}f(Q) = \mathbb{E}_{Q\in O(d)}\mathbb{E}_{P\in H}f(PQ) = \mathbb{E}_{P\in H}\mathbb{E}_{Q\in O(d)} f(PQ) = \mathbb{E}_{P\in H}\mathbb{E}_{Q\in O(d)}f(P) = \mathbb{E}_{P\in H}f(P),$$ as desired.

This lemma is crucial in the proof of the main theorem in the paper, but I cannot understand the proof and I can't see where it applies the condtion. The first equation seems not obvious to me, and the author didn't provide further details. Another problem is  that the second formula could be $$\mathbb{E}_{Q\in O(d)}\mathbb{E}_{P\in H}f(PQ)= \mathbb{E}_{Q\in O(d)} \mathbb{E}_{P\in H} f(P)=\mathbb{E}_{P\in H} f(P)$$ by the conditoin, which directly conclude the result, and why  the author prove  that as above?

Thanks for reading. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: isn't the first equality a consequence of the uniformity of the distribution of the permutation matrix $P$ on $H$?

Comment: Indeed; by the invariance of Haar measure on $O(d)$ we have $\mathbb{E}_Q f(Q) = \mathbb{E}_Q f(PQ)$ for each $P$.  Now average over $P \in H$ and interchange the average on $P$ with the expectation on $Q$ (the average on $P$ is a finite sum so no justification is needed).